# Swapping images randomly in my web

Tags: javascript, html

I want the images/r1.jpg, r2.jpg, r3.jpg, r4.jpg to use the same array I wrote at the top.
so these five images in grid as a part will automatic displaying the same content randomly.

The other `<div class="row">` which refers to my row will do the same stuff.
I have 5 parts in total. The other four parts will have their own contents.

I tried everything I can do and I changed the `id` stuff but it doesn't work.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var picRoots = ['images/r1.jpg','images/r2.jpg','images/r3.jpg','images/r4.jpg','images/r5.jpg','images/r6.jpg','images/r7.jpg','images/r8.jpg','images/r9.jpg','images/r10.jpg'];
    picRoots.sort(function(){return Math.random()>0.5?-1:1;});
    var curPic = -1;
    //preload the images for smooth animation
    var imgO = new Array();
    for(i=0; i < picRoots.length; i++) {
        imgO[i] = new Image();
        imgO[i].src = picRoots[i];
    }

    function swapImage() {
        curPic = (++curPic > picRoots.length-1)? 0 : curPic;
        imgCont.src = imgO[curPic].src;
        setTimeout(swapImage,100);
    }

    window.onload=function() {
        imgCont = document.getElementById('imgBanner1');
        swapImage();
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center" class="grid"> 
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/black.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/black.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/black.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/black.jpg" /> </div> 
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/r5.jpg" id="imgBanner1"/> </div> 
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/r1.jpg" /> </div> 
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/r2.jpg" /> </div> 
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/r3.jpg" /> </div> 
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/r4.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/black.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/black.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/black.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/black.jpg" /> </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: I don't at all understand what you're trying to do. Could you try again to describe what you're trying to achieve? Don't mention any code...that would just make it confusing.

Comment: Alright, My webpage is full of images and what I want to do is let them swapping randomly. I used grid to make my page look like a pixel tree which can be decomposed into five parts. So my question is I created an array which contains 10 images, there're 5 grid I can use the array. But I don't know how to do this.THX